# Iterating over a Parse array

Tags: ios, swift

I have an Answers String array and I am trying to iterate over it in my app and assign values to it at different indices. e.g. `Answers[index]="me"`.

How would I go about doing this in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example of a for loop in swift:

```
var myStrings = ["one","two","three"] // an array of strings

for aString in myStrings {

    var currentString = aString // access each element here

}
```